# Firefox Javascript api extension for topsites thumbs

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a simple Firefox extension that lists [topSites()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/topSites) in an HTML page which will act as newtab page.

```js
var gettingTopSites = browser.topSites.get({includeFavicon: true});
gettingTopSites.then((res) => {
 console.log(res[0]); 
})
// The output of log:
/**
Object { type: "url", url: "https://www.facebook.com/", title: "Facebook", favicon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAA4klEQVRYhWNwytnk6ZS+5bFT+qb/9MVbHjvlbPJkGBjLEY5gGDjLIXjUATR3gEvmZvo6wCd/2/8l2279v3zn7f+PX37+//////8/f//9f/3+O+0dUNh77P/bjz/+4wI0dYBP/rb/r959x2k5zR2wdPttvJbT3AFnr79GsezD55//Kyad+O+Rs5U+ifD1e9Tgr51+iih9VHMAOnAlkP1o7gBi9Y06gGwHkApevPk2sA44dfXVwDpg7d57A+uACUsvDbNEOOqAUQeMOmDUAVR0AHU6p+Q5YMtjBmp1z0l3AKR7DgApZF4e3+fcXwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" }
*/
```

As the above example, using [`topSites.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/topSites/get) method, I just able to get Favicons, but **I need** to get thumb image of the site too. The thumb images that looks like the default Firefox home page topsites. I could not able to find any option that gets the thumb image. Is there another javascript api that may get site thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a request bug for the feature: [1246693 - Provide WebExtension Thumbnail API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246693) but it is still "open".
Currently Firefox doesn't provide any API to access thumbnail stored by Firefox itself. Instead you need to create them by yourself with HTML canvas.